# Updating MeteorJS not working, running "meteor --version" or "meteor update" causes an error

Tags: meteor

I am trying to work on an old project that was using Meteor 1.8.1 at the time of its last commit. I have tried updating it by running "meteor --version" and "meteor update", but in both situations, the terminal will say "Downloading meteor-tool@1.8.1..." for about a minute before throwing the following error:

> Sorry, this project uses Meteor 1.8.1, which is not installed and could not be downloaded. Please check to make
> sure that you are online.

I am most definitely online, so I do not know what the error is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would try deleting `~/.meteor` and reinstalling it.

Comment: Is this the ~./meteor folder inside of the project directory? If so, when I do that, the directory is no longer recognized as a meteor project.

Comment: no, that would have been `.meteor`. The `~/.meteor` folder is absolute, `~` refers to your home directory. Or are you on windows?

Comment: If that does not work, wry to run `meteor update` outside of the project directory. Alternatively just go to the meteor website and run the install script it will install the latest automatically. Another thing that causes issues with installation is the proxy settings, in case you have to use a proxy or vpn

Comment: The version of Meteor running on my computer is already the latest version. so running meteor update outside of the project directory does not do anything.. It is the project that is older. I am using Windows, but I understand what you are referring to.

Comment: If this can't be resolved you may consult the forums as I can't replicate your issue